# C# Not displaying correct information on label

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the value that corresponds to a specific date, and then display that value in a label.

Here is what I have:

The data is coming from a JSON file with the following structure:

```
{
    "name": "ML4 093 Historical",
    "unit": "pounds",
    "data":[
        {
            "date": "1985-12-01",
            "value": "250"
        },
        {
            "date": "1985-11-01",
            "value": "237"
        },
        {
            "date": "1985-10-01",
            "value": "286"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, for example, for 1985-12-01, I want to get 250 and change the text of the label to 250.

On the C# side of things, I have a model class file (DataModel.cs) containing the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
        public List<Data> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then in the main file:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;

namespace test
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Label valuelabel = label3;

            string QUERY_URL = "JSON URL HERE";
                Uri queryUri = new Uri(QUERY_URL);

            using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var json_data = client.DownloadString(queryUri);
                var dataModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataModel>(json_data);
                var valueForDate = dataModel.data.Where(x => x.date == "1985-12-01").Select(v => v.value);

                var finalValue = valueForDate.ToString();

                valuelabel.Text = finalValue;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

JSON URL HERE is replaced with the actual URL in the code.

Instead of displaying the value, the label is displaying:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[test.Data.System.String]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Where().Select()` will return an `Enumerable` i.e. a list of things.

You need to select one.

```cs
var valueForDate = dataModel.data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.date == "1985-12-01")?.value;
var finalValue = valueForDate?.ToString();
valuelabel.Text = finalValue ?? "Some Default Value";
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because `Select()` will return `IEnumerable<T>`

Assuming date is unique, you can do something like this:

```
string finalValue = "";

var dataVal = dataModel.data.Where(x => x.date == "1985-12-01").FirstOrDefault();
//or use SingleOrDefault();

if (dataVal != null)
{
    finalValue = dataVal.value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your `LINQ` query to retrieve the first or default value from the filtered data.

```
var valueForDate = dataModel.data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.date == "1985-10-01")?.value;
```